PowerShell script output issue and AD
Get-CimInstance -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct -computerName test,test2,test3,test |
     where PartialProductKey | select Pscomputername,Name,@{Name='LicenseStatus';Exp={
        switch ($_.LicenseStatus)
        {
            0 {'Unlicensed'}
            1 {'licensed'}
            2 {'OOBGrace'}
            3 {'OOTGrace'}
            4 {'NonGenuineGrace'}
            5 {'Notification'}
            6 {'ExtendedGrace'}
            Default {'Undetected'}
        }
        #EndOfCaltulatedProperty
    }}

I want to export that script in CSV file, an can I put for -computerName for example from AD?


I want to export that script in CSV file

Exporting flat data to CSV is as easy as piping your objects to the Export-Csv cmdlet:
Get-CimInstance ... |Where-Object ... |Select-Object ... |Export-Csv -Path path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation



[...] can I put for -computerName for example from AD?

Assuming you have the RSAT ActiveDirectory module installed, use the Get-ADComputer cmdlet to search for target machines in your directory:
# search computers, extract name or hostname
$computerNames = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase "OU=Computers,OU=ParentOU,DC=domain,DC=tld" |ForEach-Object { 
  if($_.DNSHostName) { $_.DNSHostName } else { $_.Name }
}

# pass computer names to Get-CimInstance
Get-CimInstance ... -ComputerName $computerNames


Sorry, dont understadn what you mean with, "OU=Computers,OU=ParentOU,DC=domain,DC=tld", and with "Get-CimInstance ... |Where-Object ... |Select-Object ... |Export-Csv -Path path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation"

@Kourosh The ... are meant as placeholders, eg add your existing parameter arguments in place of .... "OU=Computers,OU=ParentOU,DC=domain,DC=tld" is just a sample OU - replace it with the DN of the Active Directory OU that contains the machines you actually want to query

Ok, you mean surely "distinguishedName"

@Kourosh DN = distinguished name :)

it seems to work, but not export it to CSV, could you help me please?

@Kourosh Did you pipe the output from Get-CimInstance to Export-Csv? :)

Yes, it does not work

@Kourosh So what makes you say "it seems to work"? Please keep in mind I can't see your screen - I don't know what you're running, and I can't see what you're seeing :)

I mean with AD and DN, it search in AD and display many informations baout Computer, but I cannot export it to a CSV file

Alright, so you know your initial AD and CIM queries work - and then what happens when you tack | Export-Csv export.csv -NoTypeInformation onto the pipeline? Is export.csv not being created in the current folder?

Yes, it cannot create any CSV. Maybe I have added the code line on the wrong line.

@Kourosh Again, I can't see your screen. Share the exact code :)

if I want to add here the code, it tell me it is to long code
